# calling mysql from a ruby program

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to do some simple statistics on data I am pulling from a database, but whenever I execute the mysql command all I get is the mysql usage listing. What is confusing to me is this command works from the command line, but not from inside my ruby script.

Command:

```
query   = 'select * from builds;'
results = `mysql -h <hostname> -u root -D build -e #{query}`
print results
```

I want to see everything in that table, but what I get is this:

> mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.37, for
>   Win32 (ia32) Copyright (C) 2002 MySQL
>   AB This software comes with ABSOLUTELY
>   NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
>   and you are welcome to modify and
>   redistribute it under the GPL license
>   Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
>   -?, --help          Display this help and exit.   -I, --help
>   Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One
>   doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but
>   startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.   -A, --no-auto-rehash
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to
>   get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start
>   of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
>   WARNING:
>                         options deprecated; use --disable-auto-rehash
>   instead.   -B, --batch         Don't
>   use history file. Disable interactive
>   behavior.

...etc

any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the [mysql gem for ruby](http://tmtm.org/en/ruby/mysql/). It allows you to operate natively instead of wrapping the command line.

But in your command I would try wrapping the query in quotes before executing it.

```
results = `mysql -h <hostname> -u root -D build -e "#{query}"`
```

Comment: The script I am writing has to run on multiple personal machines, so the only thing I am guaranteed is that they have mysql installed, I can tell if they have the gem. Also thank, you because the double quotes around query made it execute.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't just use the mysql gem?

Comment: The script I am writing has to run on multiple personal machines, so the only thing I am guaranteed is that they have mysql installed, I can tell if they have the gem.